# Do all JavaScript functions eventually boil down to either an ECMAScript or Web API specification?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, v8

**Please note that this question is from the perspective of the browser.**

I have been reading into the internals of JavaScript and realized that any piece of JavaScript code is finally executed by the engine.

As per my understanding for the engine to "know" what to do with a JavaScript function it should either:

1. Have it built into it (ECMAScript specification)
2. Embedded into it through the browser (Web API specification)

So is it right to say that any JavaScript function at its most granular level is eventually defined in either the ECMAScript specification or the Web API specification of the browser?

Comment: Browsers sometimes do not conform to the specification (and for some things, there is no specification, but a browser does it anyway)

Comment: Also user-defined functions and built-in functions from drafts/proposals.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to what you *mean* is probably "yes"; the answer to what you've *asked* is "no" ;-)

Everything you see described as "JavaScript" at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript is defined by the ECMAScript standard. Implementation-wise, that means it's built into JavaScript engines.

Browsers define a bunch of additional functionality, most notably the DOM API, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/API. Implementation-wise, these functions and objects are provided by the respective embedder of the respective JavaScript engine, i.e. in your scenario the browser. JavaScript engines provide facilities for embedders to specify such things, conceptually "define this object, with these methods, and these are the functions that should get executed when those methods are called".

Other embedders provide different functionality, e.g. Node: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/. Generally speaking, what embedders do is to expose whatever they want to the JavaScript side of things, so that programs running inside the JavaScript engine can interact with the world.

And then of course there are JavaScript functions defined in script files and modules, i.e. your own code and your imports. These are, obviously, neither built into the engine nor the browser, and yet the engine knows what to do for them, because it knows how to execute the source code you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have the language specification, that defines the syntax and the behavior of the language. And then most languages define a basic set of objects that can be used in the language (like Strings, Array, Set, Promise, ...) as part of the standard.

In addition to those basic types or API or library, or however else you want to call it, the implementation using that language could provide additional APIs, like nodejs or the browser does that you can use, or you can link against.

Sometimes the boundaries between language and its API are blurred, like for Java and its JDK.

In general, is not always clear or easy to say where to draw the border between language specification and what is part of the API/library. But most of the time primitives like numbers, booleans, ... or other things that you cannot implement yourself belong to the core of the language specification. While everything else is part of the library/additional API.

So having the language specification, the interpreter/compiler can parse and execute this:

```
function sum(a, b)  {
   return a+b;
}
let res = sum(1, 2)
```

And while debugging it, you can check the value of `res`, but there is no interaction with any API. So that is purely an interpretation of the core of the language (as defined in the ECMAScript).

As soon as you want to do something meaningful with it (displaying the value, passing it over the network, ...) you need to call an API that is either linked by you or provided by the engine.